# mitmproxy: How to configure a redirect for requests

Tags: linux, proxy

I am new to "mitmproxy" and not familiar with python. I use "mitmproxy" in mode "regular proxy".

I'd like to load a JavaScript file (in different version) from an other domain than it was specified in the loaded website.

For example, load a different jQuery version from a CDN to test, if website is compatible.

I found an example here: [redirect_requests.py](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/redirect_requests.py)

but have no idea, how I can get it into the mitmproxy.

May be there is also a solution with the [replacement feature](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/replacements.html) but I cant figure out how. I could only change path, but not the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run inline scripts in mitmproxy using `-s`, e.g.

`mitmproxy -s redirect_requests.py`

For more details, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/scripting/overview.html).